# New application that might be giving employees headaches

Tags: human-factors-engineering

A team leader came to me and told me that lately some of his team members have been complaining about frequent **headaches**.

He made a list of things that changed during the last few months, and a major change for their team was the introduction of our **new application**.

He's wondering if the application might cause the headaches, or contribute to it.

I'm no medical expert, nor a safety advisor. I care about **UX**, but more in the sense of "this is how you create an efficient, fun to use, easy to intuitively understand application", not in a sense of ergonomics or headache prevention. Well, not yet.

I'm trying to think about what could (co)cause headaches, and what we could possibly do or try to help.

For now, I've come up with:

- Let's **compare** the old application and new application, and see what changed. Is the screen **flashing** during load times? Are there a lot more **white backgrounds** with black letters? Is the **contrast** higher, is the **text** jumbled/fuzzy/smaller, did we pack more information on less screen estate?
- Let's see if **tools that reduce contrast or lighting** (f.lux like) might help.
- Maybe it's not the physical application causing the problem, but the recent **change**. People have to (re)learn the new ways of working, people need **time** to train new habits but the workload has not been reduced to give them that time. Maybe people **work** longer hours to compensate, or take less breaks, or are under constant stress. It might require more of an HR solution.

We could throw a lot of money on the problem and hire big consultants or experts, but I'd like to ask the community if any of you has experience with this kind of problem, and what possible solutions or avenues exist to gain more understanding.

Answer (score 3):

There are documented cases of bad UX having an impact on employee well-being. [One study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7785404/) showed that every 1% improvement in UX in medical software decreased the risk of user burnout by 3%. Slowness in enterprise software [wreaks havoc on concentration](https://www.fastcompany.com/90667790/the-real-reason-youre-not-more-productive-at-work-its-not-boredom-its-bad-ux?ref=uxdesignweekly) as users start multitasking. Anything that causes additional cognitive load could certainly contribute to fatigue. But even smaller changes (such as low-contrast text) can [lead to eye strain](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/low-contrast/) and micro-animations can cause "seasickness" and [trigger vestibular disorders](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/animation-from-interactions.html).

You might want to return to the source - the team lead - and ask if the users complaining of headaches would be willing to be interviewed (and you should also watch them interact with the system while thinking aloud). They might not be aware of what's causing their headaches, but you might be able to collect more information that could provide clues. How long are they working before the headaches come on? How much are they struggling? Is anything like dark mode contributing to eye strain?

If you sold a physical product to users that started to harm them, you'd want to get to the bottom of it through research - same with this.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers and the further reads!

Answer (score 1):

Addressing your first point and continuing with it: If this is an application in which the user likes to see a lot of text at once for any reason, and they can choose the font size, maybe they're shrinking it to see more (does it shrink gracefully or end up with poor character differentiation at low sizes).

A design that's added whitespace (compared to what they used before) for clearer separation may then cause them to shrink the text too much.

Slow loads will encourage users to cram more onto the screen, as will losing their place if the alternative is calling up lots of sub-windows and losing their place - think about squeezing many columns into something like a file manager to avoid right-click->properties all the time.  If loading is inherently slow and out of your control, consistent and informative behaviour is good - staring at the screen not knowing whether to do something else isn't.  It could even be faster than what they're used to so they don't take a break when they otherwise would, or even just look away.

Contrast can go either way - too much or too little, and this isn't independent of text size.

Also:

Hopefully you tested it on the same sort of hardware they use, and not only a developer's top of the range monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. We'll investigate into it.